# Count age from today's birthday

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have made a script that displays persons who are having their birthday today.
Beside this, I would like to show the age of those persons.
I have found many workable solutions, but I don't know how to implement in my current code.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW())";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<p>".$row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"]."</p>";
}
}
else
{
echo "There are no birthdays today";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: This is of course only correct at and after the day of your birthday. But since you are displaying the age only **at the day of the birthday** this equation is correct in your case.

Isn't the age simply the current year minus the year of the birth? So you can change your select to:

```sql
SELECT *, YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dob) AS age FROM birthday WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW())
```

or you can do it the php way:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM birthday WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW()) AND DAY(dob) = DAY(NOW())";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$current_year = date("Y");
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $birthday = date_parse($row["dob"]);
        $age = null;
        if(is_array($birthday)){
            $age = $current_year - $birthday["year"];
        }
        echo "<p>".$row["first_name"]." ".$row["last_name"]." is now " + $age + " years old.</p>";
    }
}
else{
    echo "There are no birthdays today";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: That's the definition of the age, isn't it? https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/age#Synonyms "[P]eriod (in years[...]) something has been alive". That is the year of the birth minus the current year. Example: You are born in 1980, 2020 - 1980 = 40. That's your age (at and after the day of your birthday).

Comment: No. The question is about "displaying the age **at the day of the birthday**". That's why one can ignore the days. The age is only shown and caluclated in December 2020, on your birthay.